# LookUpEdit when bind to two BindingSources not working

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, bindingsource

I have a problem where value from `LookUpEdit` is not updated in `DataBindings` added DataSource. What I have done is that I have `LookUpEdit` control on the form and id set LookUpEdit DataSource, Value and DisplayMember. Then I added `DataBindings` with second BindingSource where changed value in LookUpEdit is not updated in this second BindingSource:

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = // here i get IQueryable 
BindingSource bindingSource2 = // here i get IQueryable where one field from bindingSource1 is set as foreign key

lookUpEdit1.Properties.DataSource = bindingSource1.
lookUpEdit1.Properties.ValueMember = "Id";
lookUpEdit1.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";

lookUpEdit1.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", bindingSource2, "fk_id", true,     DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Sometimes I get `System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException was unhandled too`. The second BindingSource is set as DataSource of the GridControl, i.e. GridView.

Comment: Are you trying to filter the content of the dropdown, by a selection done by user, prior to selecting this dropdown?

Comment: No. What i have is GridControl that as DataSource has bindingSource2. My form have LookUpEdit controls on the left side and GridControl on the left side. So when user change row in table, value i n lookUpEdit is also changed. But when i change value in LookUpEdit, the value in table is not changed or i got exception as above. Is this possible at all, when not then please tell me how can i do it.

Comment: I have noticed that bindingSource2 is updated so long as i don't select another row in GridView, than i get ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException.

Comment: I think i found a solution. I set column ColumnEdit to repositoryLookUpEdit and most important i set           gridView1.OptionsBehavior.CacheValuesOnRowUpdating = CacheRowValuesMode.Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

set gridView1.OptionsBehavior.CacheValuesOnRowUpdating = CacheRowValuesMode.Disabled.